# Is it acceptable to fork a PHP script to continue email processing and to return data to the user?

Tags: php, cron, swiftmailer

I'm adding email functionality to an existing website and I am trying to integrate it in a way that requires the least user wait time.

My latest plan is to fork a user's request when the application gets to sending the actual email so I can return a page the user with a message saying their message is sending. I want to prevent long delays resulting from a user request requiring many separate emails to be sent.

I have considered (and even implemented) a cron job solution, but I think it's too much work to setup -- I'd like to be able plunk this on a Linux box and not have to worry about setting up cron jobs.

Other than issues with creating a new database connection and closing out the user's session, is there anything that screams "don't do it this way" before I manage emails with `pcntl_fork?` Are there benefits to a cron job over forking I'm not seeing?

Comment: sure do it all the time, usually `exec('semdemail.php > /dev/null &');`

Comment: some smart-arse will post "use ajax" but just ignore them

Comment: So my only thought on the exec would be, what if two users made the request? Would I have to handle any race conditions?

Comment: unlikely, but that would depends on what was in `sendmail.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to implement an database supported email queue, which in its simplest form could look like this:

1. When the user submits the form, write the message parameters (sender, recipient, message, etc.) into a database table, including a timestamp (e.g. in a column named `created_at`) when the message has been submitted.
2. You can then immediately show the success-page to your users.
3. Let a cronjob process the database table (`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at DESC`), send the emails and either delete the rows from the table or mark the entries as sent (e.g. with an additional column `sent_at`).

You *can* fork the PHP process, but this makes coding and portability of your application more difficult, so I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: i would say sending the email address to another script for immediate processing was simpler, your approach looks like overkill

Comment: I guess this depends on the point of view - in my opinion, forking PHP processes just to send emails is overkill as well :). Sending emails as such is not an expensive process - if the point is to be able to handle a lot of requests at once, forking processes does not help, as the number of concurrent processes is limited - deferring the email send process to a cronjob will not result in a bottleneck.

Comment: I didn't consider the process count if I had a good deal of concurrent requests.  I leaned toward forking because my shared host (ouch..) kills PHP scripts after 15 minutes. I think I'll go with the CRON job route with this information.          To those who have a similar script time limit, you can reset your host's timer by forking the script and getting rid of the parent (This has allowed me to run a daemon-like script without the risk of my host shutting it down)

Comment: Codeing around your host s rules seems like a bad idea to me. Move to a host that supports your requirements